# Say "one moment" after a Gather finishes

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I can't seem to find any documentation on this, but I'd like to say "one moment" in a Gather block in between when a user stops speaking and when the speech recognition processor delivers the words they said (since anecdotally this can take a few seconds and result in dead air in the meantime).

I can't seem to find anything like that in the documentation.  All of the examples are for things like:

```
<Response>
   <Gather>
      <Say>Voice prompt to read to the user before collection</Say>
      <Say>Say more things if you want</Say>
   </Gather>
   <Say>Something to say if the user doesn't provide feedback</Say>
</Response>
```

Having around 5 seconds of dead air isn't the worst thing ever, but it lacks polish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is nothing to provide for a message after the user finishes speaking to the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) and after the speech result is ready and sent to the [`action` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action), however I think you might be characterising the delay wrong.

Twilio streams the voice to the speech detection service, so we get real time results (you can get partial results by setting a [`partialResultCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#partialresultcallback)). Instead, the time that elapses between the end of the caller speaking and the `action` being called is based on the [`timeout`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#timeout) which is 5 seconds by default.

What I would suggest is that you try different values for the [`speechTimout` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#speechtimeout) including `auto`, which "will stop speech recognition when there is a pause in speech and return the results immediately."

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, but it sounds very reasonable.  TIA